# Find hidden input when inside a td tag that is near it in same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to find a value of a hidden input in same table row but it seems that i cannot access it with how i am trying to.

```
function setDateTimeOn(elm) {
    var formattedDate = GetCurrentDateTime(); //get formatted date
    $(elm) //clicked button
    .parent("td") // container td
    .next() // next td
    .find("span")
    .text(formattedDate);

     console.log(elm);

     var hdn = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
     console.log(hdn);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/xf12y7y4/

What I am searching for is this

```
<input type="hidden" name="GridView1:_ctl2:hndTxtId" id="GridView1__ctl2_hndTxtId" value="3601">
```

I want the value 3601 , it is in the same tr

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="GridView1:_ctl2:hndTxtId" id="GridView1__ctl2_hndTxtId" value="3601">
    </td>
    <td style="width:50px;">    <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblVehicle0">413</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="button" id="GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0" name="GridView1:_ctl2:AddButton0" value="On" class="btn-blue" onclick="setDateTimeOn(this)">
    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
     <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblStormTimeOn"></span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

I see it spit out the complete input element tag but the var hdn , I try to do a console.log(hdn) and it is undefined.

Comment: try `$(elm)` instead of `$(this)` - `this` refers to the method, not to the element. http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/xf12y7y4/

Comment: Actually, `this` is the `window` in that context...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using:

```
var hdn = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

And `this` here is the global Window object. You want to use the element:

```
var hdn = $(elm).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf12y7y4/1/)